# Generating DTO classes from DbContext via Text Templating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, dto

Please bear with me as I am new to MVC and WCF and may be asking the wrong question.

I am trying to write a WCF service and an MVC web application over an existing project that contains entity, data and business layers. The MVC and WCF components would then replace an older web service and WebForms application which worked very diferently and did not use modern practices.

I see the need to generate DTO objects against all Entity objects and was wondering how we can generate them. Through reflection, digging into the DbContext or some other method.

Furthermore, I also want to generate repository partial classes minimizing the need to maintain hand-written code for a large data model.

How do large development teams do this?

Comment: see http://entitiestodtos.codeplex.com/